# Why does the Stack Overflow mobile site recommend the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-overflow-app

When I do my research I start from Google and then I come to Stack Overflow to view questions and answer. Before I installed the Stack Overflow Android App, I used the mobile browser (Chrome) to visit the Stack Overflow website.

I noticed that at the bottom of the mobile website, there is a suggestion to download the Stack Exchange app (image below).

[image: StackOverflow mobile websites suggest download StackExchange app]

Why does Stack Overflow suggest to download the Stack Exchange app instead of the dedicated one (Stack Overflow)?

I'm just curious:)

I am not asking for other Stack Exchange's websites because they don't have their own app and some of them are subdomains of Stack Exchange.com (which explains to me the suggestion to download the Stack Exchange app).

Comment: The app works for all the sites in the network; but now that you brought it up, why *do* they want us to use that? I vastly prefer visiting Stack Overflow in the browser on my mobile phone, and from what I hear, many people share this sentiment.

Comment: Thank you @tripleee. Yes the app works for all the sites in the network, I used that before I discovered the StackOverflow app. If I can ask, why do you prefer the browser?

Comment: The web browser is more suitable for my Stack Overflow habits, starting with the ability to view questions in separate tabs e.g. when looking for duplicates or background information.

Comment: I agree with tripleee overall but back when I used SO a lot there was really no substitute for a proper computer with a keyboard and mouse. That still seems to be the case. I think people who do this stuff on mobile are just crippling themselves for no good reason frankly. Do you really need to write SO answers on the bus?

Comment: The website is so much faster than the app. In the app I spend ages looking at loading icons and such. Click, wait, swipe, wait, click, wait.. etc..

Comment: The app is useful for receiving push notifications when somebody @'s you but I also use the browser for everything else.

Comment: Thats all about SRP man. Single Responsibility Principle. StackExchange has Single Responsibility. You dont create many classes for one purpose. You create one class, extend it as needed to satisfy other needs.

Comment: The website is all I need. If I'm not on SO, I won't be responding to someone if they @ me until I'm online later anyways, so I don't need push notifications to annoy me when I'm not available to respond. I really can't find anything about the app that the mobile site isn't as good or better at.

Comment: "Do you really need to write SO answers on the bus" - do you realize some people are on mobile for 100% of their web browsing?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky it would appear to me that a developer would have a quite vast need for a bigger screen and physical keyboard to be anywhere near productive. I highly doubt there are people who use their mobile for all web browsing and development needs. Of course there can be "airgapped" scenarios where development machines aren't connected to the Internet, but that's a whole different story...

Comment: As I understand it the Stack Exchange app is the main and preferred app. The Stack Overflow app was created because of brand recognition.

Comment: @DavyM Absolutely. In fact the searching and browsing on mobile site is much faster than the app.

Comment: @AshleyMedway +1 for the only comment that's anything like an answer, rather than an opinion about the merits/demerits of the app.

Comment: I mean it _couldn't possibly_ be that they just forgot to change that in the mobile footer....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there's been no official response I'll post my understanding of the apps. The Stack Exchange is the main app that they want you to use and the Stack Overflow app was created due to brand recognition. See this [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/).

> Shakespeare famously wrote that a rose by any other name would smell as sweet … but, alas! ‘tis not so for mobile apps. At least not the Stack Exchange mobile app that we launched back in 2014. Without that sweet Stack Overflow name, some of you never discovered that you could use it to view, answer, post and vote on Stack Overflow questions.

So to answer your question, the reason it would recommend the Stack Exchange app is because the business would prefer you to use that one.